# What is switch in VBA, a statement or a function?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I've always considered things like `for loop`, `if statement` and `select case` to be statements while `switch` to be a function. After some Google search, I  realized that `switch` is most of the time referred to as switch statement.

At [tech on the net](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php), it was categorically classified as a function but together with `for loop`, `if statement` etc.

My question: is `switch` a statement or a function in excel VBA? Also, what exactly differentiates a statement from a function?

Comment: Did you try the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/switch-function)?

Comment: ...and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/writing-visual-basic-statements

Comment: No, I didn't try the doc but I get it now. Thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 4):

`Switch` is a function, as is clear in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/switch-function).

In the Object Browser, you can see that `Switch` is a function and member of `VBA.Interaction`.

[image]